# Clojure: construct function based on variables dynamcally?

Tags: clojure, higher-order-functions

For the following data:

```
(def occurrence-data '(["John" "Artesyn" 1 31.0] ["Mike" "FlexPower" 2 31.0] ["John" "Eaton" 1 31.0]))
```

I would like to have a function:

```
(defn visit-numbers
  "Produce a map from coordinates to number of customer visits from occurrence records."
  [coordinates occurrences]
  (let [selector ??? ; a function that would be equivalent to (juxt #(nth % c1) #(nth % c2) ..), where c1, c2, ... are elements of coordinates 
        ]
    (group-by selector occurrences)
  )
```

For example, for coordinates = [1 3]

It should be

```
(group-by (juxt #(nth % 1) #(nth % 3)) occurrence-data)
```

I guess that it should be possible? I tried to use some list expression but has not figured out yet.

My experiment of following:

```
(def selector (list 'juxt '#(nth % 1) '#(nth % 3)))
(group-by selector occurrence-data)
```

Got error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
           core.clj:6600 clojure.core/group-by[fn]
       protocols.clj:143 clojure.core.protocols/fn
        protocols.clj:19 clojure.core.protocols/fn[fn]
        protocols.clj:31 clojure.core.protocols/seq-reduce
        protocols.clj:48 clojure.core.protocols/fn
        protocols.clj:13 clojure.core.protocols/fn[fn]
           core.clj:6289 clojure.core/reduce
           core.clj:6602 clojure.core/group-by
```

I have two problems to solve:

1. How to make selector a function?
2. How to dynamic construct such function based coordinates?

Thanks for your pointers, and help!

I also guess that using macro might also be possible to do it?

Or am I using too complicated method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call juxt directly to create your function, and define selector to hold that function:

```
(def selector (juxt #(nth % 1) #(nth % 3)))
```

To make it dynamically, create a function-creating function:

```
(defn make-selector [& indexes] (apply juxt (map (fn[i] #(nth % i)) indexes)))
```

REPL example:

```
core> (def occurrence-data '(["John" "Artesyn" 1 31.0] ["Mike" "FlexPower" 2 31.0] ["John" "Eaton" 1 31.0]))
#'core/occurrence-data
core> (def selector (juxt #(nth % 1) #(nth % 3)))
#'core/selector
core> (group-by selector occurrence-data)
{["Artesyn" 31.0] [["John" "Artesyn" 1 31.0]], ["FlexPower" 31.0] [["Mike" "FlexPower" 2 31.0]], ["Eaton" 31.0] [["John" "Eaton" 1 31.0]]}
core> (group-by (make-selector 0 1 2) occurrence-data)
{["John" "Artesyn" 1] [["John" "Artesyn" 1 31.0]], ["Mike" "FlexPower" 2] [["Mike" "FlexPower" 2 31.0]], ["John" "Eaton" 1] [["John" "Eaton" 1 31.0]]}
```

Comment: I think the OP was mixing up functions and macros. You don't need to quote function bodies.

Comment: Your answer misses the second part of the OP's question: how to *dynamically* create such a function depending on a set of coordinates. It's trivial to do this in Clojure using an anonymous function that closes over the coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost `index`

```
(clojure.set/index occurrence-data [2 3])
;=>
;    {{3 31.0, 2 2} #{["Mike" "FlexPower" 2 31.0]},
;     {3 31.0, 2 1} #{["John" "Eaton" 1 31.0] ["John" "Artesyn" 1 31.0]}}
```

Where you can see, for example, that there are two records that share the same values at coordinates 2 and 3, those values being 1 and 31.0.

If you wanted to strip back out the indices and map to a count, then

```
(reduce-kv 
  (fn [a k v] (conj a {(vals k) (count v)})) 
  {} 
  (clojure.set/index occurrence-data [2 3]))
;=> {(31.0 1) 2, (31.0 2) 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the existing solution and elegant reduction!

Answer (score 1):

Define

```
(defn group-by-indices [ns coll]
  (group-by #(mapv % ns) coll))
```

then, for example,

```
(group-by-indices [1] occurrence-data)
;{["Artesyn"] [["John" "Artesyn" 1 31.0]],
; ["FlexPower"] [["Mike" "FlexPower" 2 31.0]],
; ["Eaton"] [["John" "Eaton" 1 31.0]]}
```

and

```
(group-by-indices [2 3] occurrence-data)
;{[1 31.0] [["John" "Artesyn" 1 31.0] ["John" "Eaton" 1 31.0]],
; [2 31.0] [["Mike" "FlexPower" 2 31.0]]}
```

If you want to keep the selection map, use `select-keys` instead of `mapv`. Then we're getting close to [A.Webb's use of `clojure.set/index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25561676/1562315), which is, other things being equal, the method of choice.

Comment: Thanks! Amazingly elegant using mapv or map and group-by to achieve the goals.